# How to unregister an android device from a push channel on parse.com?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I registered an Android App for push notifications with parse.com. Now I want to remove a channel for some devices?.

I register the channels with:

```
channels = new LinkedList<String>();
channels.add(getString(R.string.shirt_channel));
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().put("channels", channels);
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used an older version of the Parse.com Android library.

If you use Parse-1.7.0 you subscribe to a channel with:

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(getString(R.string.shirt_channel));
```

and unsubscribe the same channel with:

```
ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground(getString(R.string.shirt_channel));
```